# Make Terraform resource key multiline

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am declaring a `google_logging_metric` resource in Terraform (using version `0.11.14`)

I have the following declaration

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "my_metric" {
  description = "Check for logs of some cron job\t"
  name        = "mycj-logs"
  filter      = "resource.type=\"k8s_container\" AND resource.labels.cluster_name=\"${local.k8s_name}\" AND resource.labels.namespace_name=\"workable\" AND resource.labels.container_name=\"mycontainer-cronjob\" \nresource.labels.pod_name:\"my-pod\""
  project     = "${data.terraform_remote_state.gke_k8s_env.project_id}"

  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = "DELTA"
    value_type  = "INT64"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the `filter` field multiline?

The existence of the `local` variable `"${local.k8s_name}` makes it a bit challenging.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#strings

Comment: I literally found that by googling, `terraform multiline string`

Comment: part of my question is whether this section `=\"${local.k8s_name}\"` is parsed appropriately

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#strings)

> String values are simple and represent a basic key to value mapping
>   where the key is the variable name. An example is:
>
> ```
> variable "key" {
>   type    = "string"
>   default = "value"
> }
> ```
>
> A multi-line string value can be provided using heredoc syntax.
>
> ```
> variable "long_key" {
>   type = "string"
>   default = <<EOF
> This is a long key.
> Running over several lines.
> EOF
> }
> ```

Comment: EOF or EOH doesnt work . It gives error when I tried to set `member = <<EOF ... EOF` on multiple lines. Stick to normal double quoted string format

Answer (score 4):

This has changed as of mid-2022.
The heredoc syntax has been changed to:

```
<<EOT/<<-EOT 
... 
EOT
```

per Hashicorp documentation:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings

^^^ Find 'heredoc strings'

The previous answer's example should now be:

```
variable "long_key" {
  type = string
  default = <<EOT
This is a long key.
Running over several lines.
EOT
}
```